# change color of drawable in a button Android

Tags: java, android, button, drawable

I don't understand I'm setting a button with a drawable with che color blue but I see the button red (that's my primary color) but I don't know how to change the color without modifying the *colorPrimary* attribute.

That's my button:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_change_circle_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></Button>
```

And that's my brawable resource:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="@color/blue">
  <path
      android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
      android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12c0,5.52 4.48,10 10,10s10,-4.48 10,-10C22,6.48 17.52,2 12,2zM12.06,19v-2.01c-0.02,0 -0.04,0 -0.06,0c-1.28,0 -2.56,-0.49 -3.54,-1.46c-1.71,-1.71 -1.92,-4.35 -0.64,-6.29l1.1,1.1c-0.71,1.33 -0.53,3.01 0.59,4.13c0.7,0.7 1.62,1.03 2.54,1.01v-2.14l2.83,2.83L12.06,19zM16.17,14.76l-1.1,-1.1c0.71,-1.33 0.53,-3.01 -0.59,-4.13C13.79,8.84 12.9,8.5 12,8.5c-0.02,0 -0.04,0 -0.06,0v2.15L9.11,7.83L11.94,5v2.02c1.3,-0.02 2.61,0.45 3.6,1.45C17.24,10.17 17.45,12.82 16.17,14.76z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: If you want to handle the background yourself, then you can specify `<android.widget.Button>` or `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>` tags instead. That will prevent the library's inflater factory from substituting `MaterialButton`s for plain `<Button>` tags.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but I don't understand, if I do ctrl click on `<Button>` I already see android.widget.Button class

Comment: Yeah, that is a bit confusing. What you're seeing in the layout editor is just what your IDE can tell you about it from only that XML. It's not smart enough to know that this layout will eventually be inflated at runtime with a specialized `LayoutInflater.Factory` that substitutes `MaterialButton` for `<Button>`. (It was a terrible decision on their part, IMO, to have Material Components do that silently.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using AppCompatButton is not your option you can always change backgroundTint of the button to your desired color:

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_change_circle_24"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></Button>
```

Comment: They're still going to end up with a `MaterialButton`, though, which should not set `android:background` at all: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#:~:text=Do%20not%20use%20the%20android%3Abackground%20attribute..

Comment: Yeah, true, I've just tried that.